# Android: don't apply style to some Dialog inner views

Tags: android, dialog, styles

I have a Dialog with a custom layout in it. I created a style for this `Dialog` since I want it to have rounded corners, border and a certain background. The only way I found to see rounded corners right is to create the `Dialog` like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(me, R.style.MyDialog);
```

Inside this `Dialog` I have a `TableLayout` (just 2 rows) and a couple of buttons. The problem I'm facing is that the style R.style.MyDialog is also applied to the Dialog's inner views, so my TableLayout and all its rows have rounded corners and a stroke. Is there any way to avoid it without having to apply again a style to all the views affected?

I tried to create an empty style and apply it to the TableLayout and its rows, but it's not working.

```
<style name="EmptyStyle" parent="AppTheme"></style>
```

I apply it in the inner view layout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/result_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    style="@style/EmptyStyle"
    >

    <TableRow
        style="@style/EmptyStyle">
    ...
    </TableRow>
    ...
</TableLayout>
```

And this layout is added to the Dialog:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(me, R.style.MyDialog);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.resultdialog);
```

Thanks!